# PHP Timezone not working correctly

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

So we have in-house servers here in this EDT part of the USA `America/New_York` and for someone reason, this [SSCCE][1] code is not working.

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get() . " <br />";

$dateCal = "2015-06-22 13:00:00"; // EDT Time
$schedule_date = new DateTime($dateCal, new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago") );

echo $dateCal  . " <br />"; // 2015-06-22 13:00:00
echo date_format($schedule_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s T'); // 2015-06-22 13:00:00 CDT
?>
```

The output results in:

```
UTC 
2015-06-22 13:00:00 
2015-06-22 13:00:00 CDT
```

When the 2nd time should be 12 NOON, instead of 1PM.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why should it be noon? You never change the timezone.

Comment: So how would you propose I make the date in accordance with that user profile's timezone? (They have theirs to America/Chicago while we are in America/New_York)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but all that code is doing is creating a new DateTime object with an "America/Chicago" timezone and spaffing it out again... you're not actually doing anything with it?

Comment: I am an idiot. I just realized my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not quite handling timezones correctly

```
// set the datetime in the EDT timezone
$schedule_date = new DateTime("2015-06-22 13:00:00", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York") );
echo $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T'). " <br />"; // 2015-06-22 13:00:00
// change it to CDT
$schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T'). " <br />"; // 2015-06-22 12:00:00
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/386280)

Comment: Of course. Set first then echo. But setting it by creating a new timezone and then applying it. I see where I went wrong. Thank you.